# Linq receiving unable to create value type of model, only primitive types or enumeration types are supported

Tags: c#, linq

I'm receiving the following error:

> {"Unable to create a constant value of type 'OnlineContactChangeTableModel'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."}

When this code is executed:

```
    List<OnlineContactChangeTableModel> ret = new List<OnlineContactChangeTableModel>();
    ret = db.Address.AsNoTracking().Where(a => a.IsProcessed == false && 
                                          a.IsDeleted == false).ToList()
             .Select(aa => new OnlineContactChangeTableModel(aa)).ToList();
    ret.AddRange(db.Email.AsNoTracking().Where(a => !ret.Any(rr => rr.Id == a.Id) &&  
                                          a.IsProcessed == false && 
                                          a.IsDeleted == false).ToList()
             .Select(aa => new OnlineContactChangeTableModel(aa)).ToList());
```

The error is occurring on the AddRange line.  When it hits this line ret does have records and the Id field is not null for any of them.  The Id field is equivalent to a person Id.  I only want them in the list 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new list to keep track of the Ids and that fixed my issue:

```
List<OnlineContactChangeTableModel> ret = new List<OnlineContactChangeTableModel>();
List<int> lIds = new List<int>();
ret = db.Address.AsNoTracking().Where(a => a.IsProcessed == false && 
                                      a.IsDeleted == false).ToList()
         .Select(aa => new OnlineContactChangeTableModel(aa)).ToList();

lIds.AddRange(ret.Select(s => s.Id).ToList();

ret.AddRange(db.Email.AsNoTracking().Where(a => !lIds.Any(rr => rr == a.Id) &&  
                                      a.IsProcessed == false && 
                                      a.IsDeleted == false).ToList()
         .Select(aa => new OnlineContactChangeTableModel(aa)).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `.ToList()` after `.AsNoTracking()`, then it will work !

```
ret = db.Address.AsNoTracking()
                .ToList()
                .Where(a => a.IsProcessed == false && a.IsDeleted == false)
                .ToList()
                .Select(aa => new OnlineContactChangeTableModel(aa))
                .ToList();
```